# Cassini: ASPX file: This type of page is not served

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

When running a ASP.NET 3.5 project in Visual Studio 2010's Casini, I receive the following error:

> This type of page is not served.
>
> Description: The type of page you have
> requested is not served because it has
> been explicitly forbidden.  The
> extension '.aspx' may be incorrect.
> Please review the URL below and make
> sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /default.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
> Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952;
> ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

This is a project running in visual studio 2010 in windows 7 64 bit on .NET 3.5

The same error occurs in IIS, although IIS is configured to handle .aspx:

[image: IIS settings]

I also executed aspnet_regiis /i from the 2.0.50727 .net folder:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -i
>
> Finished installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).

Comment: Just got the same error here. I'm also not able to find out why it is happening...

Comment: Do you have any explicit entries in your sites web.config under system.webServer/modules or system.webServer/handlers that might be interfering with the ASP.NET handler? Also, have you specified any authentication rules - you sometimes see this when IIS is issuing a 403 forbidden response.

Answer (score 1):

I concluded the following

1. Check the target framework of your  project.
2. Also check if default.aspx exists on the disk. If you are redirecting or accessing the page 
   try using ~/DirName/Pagename.aspx if inside root , in some directory or ~/page.aspx if in the root itself.
   Also .Aspx files are by default added to IIS or any webserver that supports asp.net.